# Joining three tables clarification

Tags: sql, oracle, join

This isn't a question I need a direct answer to, I Just need to know how, from a philosophical point of view, how many tables I would need to join.

Say I have 3 tables :

```
TableA : 
Account_Number | Name | Address

TableB : 
Account_Number | Occupation | Salary

TableC :
Account_Number | Model | Make
```

These tables all have a column in common.  If I was to join these tables together to get a the columns in each table that has a matching account number, i would do an inner join to return only records that are matching.

in the query, I would have something like :

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Address, T2.Occupation, T2.Salary, T3.Model, T3.Make
FROM TableA T1
INNER JOIN TableB T2 ON T1.Account_Number=T2.Account_Number
INNER JOIN TableC T3 ON T2.Account_Number=T3.Account_Number /Do I need to join T3 to T1 or is this handled by having T1 and T2 joined together?
WHERE ??.AccountNumber=1234123412341234 /Would any Table work in the WHERE clause here since we are all looking for the same account_number in each table?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT T1.Name, T1.Address, T2.Occupation, T2.Salary, T3.Model, T3.Make
  FROM TableA T1
    INNER JOIN TableB T2 ON T1.Account_Number=T2.Account_Number
 INNER JOIN TableC T3 ON T2.Account_Number=T3.Account_Number /Do I need to     join T3 to T1 or is this handled by having T1 and T2 joined together?
 WHERE T1.AccountNumber=1234123412341234
```

Inner join will return only records which are present in the table you are joining ,. So in your select your use TableA so in where clause you should use T1.AccountNumber

For more information please look this link http://www.sql-join.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider with respect to your data model. For example

o What is the relationship between these tables? Is there one? Is the fact that there is an Account_Number column just a coincidence
o Assuming there is a relationship, what is the cardinality? For example, for any given row in Table A, how many corresponding rows are there in Table B; 0, 1 or more than one. Similarly from Table B to table A; and similarly between Tables B and C.
o. Depending on the meaning of these relationships, you could find yourself in a situation called a "fan trap". This is a situation where you have a fanning out of relationships:

```
      B
     / \
    /   \
   A     C
```

It easier to describe with an Example.

Lets say:

A is a table of Sales Reps
B is a table of Branches
C is a table of Accounts

So each Sales Rep works in one Branch (cardinality=1), and each Branch has 1 or more Sales Rep ( cardinality=Many )
Each Branch handles many Accounts, and each Account is held at one Branch

This is a perfectly valid data model

However, from this data model, if you want to find out which sales rep handles which account, you cannot. This is the so called Fan trap. In this particular example, you would probably solve this be having a relationship directly between Sales Rep and Accounts; even though it may look redundant.

So I know this is a long answer to your question, but it elaborates on the short answer, which is "It depends" :)

Answer (score 0):

BobC is right concerning semantics, it depends.

Syntactically, your example is fully correct and just how I would do it too. Joining applies to just 2 objects/result sets and both have to be in the condition when you don't want a cross join. Furthermore it doesn't matter which of the identically account# columns from the first join you use in the second join.

As for the WHERE condition, if only one of the tables got an Index or Partionkey, use that one. Else, use the table on which the WHERE statement gives you the fewest rows.

Joining often benefits from starting with the smallest tables/result sets. Although Oracle will optimize your statement respecting the gathered statistics anyway.